# Redirecting specific URLs to AWS Cloudfront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

So I have a Web App running in AWS on EC2 and I have an AWS Cloudfront distribution which serves up some custom content from an S3 bucket when the EC2 site is down.

I now have a requirement to serve up some files from the Web App that are stored in S3. How would I go about sending request made to https://example.com/files/* to the Cloudfront distribution? Route 53?

Comment: What is your failover process of redirecting users to your s3 bucket? Are you using Route 53 health checks?

Comment: @MattHouser - Yes, failover is carried out by a Route 53 Health Check.

Comment: Is it possible to  put the EC2 instance behind an ELB? will cost going to be an issue?- if not you can solve this by adding another origin to CF

Answer (score 0):

So I came back to this after digesting the comments made and considering if this was indeed the correct approach. I then came to the conclusion that it was not.

Since the Cloudfront distribution is only accessible using the applications standard URLs when the DNS health check fails and the DNS fails over using the same URLs doesn't work.

The option could be to directly access the Cloudfront distribution with the alias target used by the DNS health check. I would then have to add extra controls to stop public access to files stored.

Second option is to create S3 Endpoints that can access the S3 bucket and have the app serve up the content in the bucket.

Constructive comments are most welcome.